# "Substring" a GridView BoundField object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Can anyone tell me how to substring a GridView BoundField object please?

I tried this so far and it hasn't worked. Thank you.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# ChopString((string)Eval("description")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What do you need to get out of the string? Is it always the same length?

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work either: `Text='<%# Left(Eval("description"),60) %>'`. I need the first 60 characters.

Comment: @TimA `Left` is a VB.NET function.

Comment: Your ChopString function, have you placed a breakpoint there to analyze the return value?  What isn't working exactly...is ChopString returning too many or too few characters?

Comment: It says `The name 'ChopString' does not exist in the current context` (when I try to access the page that contains the gridview). I don't know how to use breakpoints yet. Maybe as previous user, said, these may not be ASP.NET functions?

Comment: Your ChopString needs to be either protected or public method defined in the page when used in-line such as your example, though there are other methods to achieve it as well.

Comment: But I don't use it in the code-behind (C#) file. I use it in the ASPX source. Can you make protected/public/etc in the asp.net source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use substring.

```
   Eval("description").ToString().Substring(0,60)
```

I believe thats all you need.

Answer (score 2):

> It says The name 'ChopString' does not exist in the current context

Make sure your `ChopString` method is either protected or public in the page's codebehind.

> Maybe as previous user, said, these may not be ASP.NET functions?

`ChopString` is not a built-in function.  Make your own:

**ASPX Codebehind**

Example:

```
protected string ChopString(string val)
{
    //Check that val is a valid candidate for Substring, i.e. check for nulls, appropriate length, etc
    //...
    //...
    string returnVal = val.Substring(0,60); //Return first 60 chars
    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Eval("description").ToString().Substring(0, 60);
```