# How to use Substring in Bind text

Tags: asp.net, gridview, substring, bind

I am binding a Gridview with some data and I have taken labels in template field and I am binding the data to that label's text property,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Proceedings" SortExpression="PROCEEDINGS" ItemStyle-Width="60px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblProceedings" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Value" Text='<%# Bind("PROCEEDINGS") %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("PROCEEDINGS") %>'></asp:Label>                                                        
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle Wrap="true" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
```

I want the length of the Bound text till 10 characters how to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblProceedings" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Value" Text='<%# Eval("PROCEEDINGS") == null ? "empty" : Eval("PROCEEDINGS").ToString().Substring(0,10)%>'
```

or check this link [Substring in a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088633/substring-a-gridview-boundfield-object)

I hope that help.

Comment: even if there is no data 2nd part of ternary is taken by this code,that means when there is no Data then also 2nd part is executed, i tried "" instead of null also

Comment: Yes I forget to ask you that if it is DBnull or string.empty. but I am so glad that you got the solution.

Comment: i have modified your post because Eval("PROCEEDINGS") == null or Eval("PROCEEDINGS") == "" is not detected Eval("PROCEEDINGS").ToString == "" is detected,Thank You very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

10Label has no MaxLangth property, you can use here textbox and give MaxLength="10", and style it as a lable.

EDIT:

You can use substring like this:

```
<asp:label id="lDesc" runat ="server" text ='<%# (Eval("Description") .Length>=10) ? Eval("Description").SubString(0,10) :Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: yes this is possible, do you have text more than 10 character and want to show it in tooltip then i prefer use substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
Text='<%# Eval("PROCEEDINGS").ToString().Substring(0,9) %>'
```

Or you can write a function in .cs file like this.

```
protected getString(string str)
{
 return (str..Substring(0,9));
}
```

And use this in gridview label as

```
Text='<%# getString(Eval("PROCEEDINGS").ToString()) %>'
```