# how to bind substring into gridview and

Tags: asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged, rowdatabound, rowcommand

I am using a gridview to show my db table data. but there is a column called "Description "  with 1000 characters. I don't want bond whole string into gridview. How I bind **only first 100 characters into gridview** column???

when I click select button I want make to **popup window with selected column details.** At this moment I want to **show all characters of   Description column**.

I have **already created popup window and other things**. but still I could not get first 100 letters of "description column" and bind it into gridview. How can I do this ? And how I get whole string into popup window?

ALL ANSWERS ARE WELCOME.. PLEASE HELP ME.

THANK YOU

Comment: How do you bind your data to your gridview?

Comment: grdInquiry.DataBind();

grdInquiry is the name of gridview...

Comment: Ok, so you seem to have an Inquiry class or model. Please see and try my answer.

Comment: You can go through the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088633/substring-a-gridview-boundfield-object

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650791/limit-text-size-in-gridview-column

Answer (score 0):

If you have an entity that you bind to your gridview, you can do this:

First, add a new property:

```
[NotMapped]
public string CutDescription
{
    get
    {
        if (Description.Length <= 1000)
        {
            return Description;
        }
        return Description.Substring(0, 1000) + "...";
    }
}
```

Then you can bind this to your gridview:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CutDescription" HeaderText="Description" />
```

This is just one way to do it. Hope it helps.

EDIT:
Another way using RowDatabound event:

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.Row;
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Just change the index of the cell 
        var description = row.Cells[1].Text;
        if (description.Length > 100)
        {
            row.Cells[1].Text = description.Substring(0, 100) + "...";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I put this code under Protected void Grid_RowDataBound{}
but then cannot return a value... How can I solve this ??

Answer (score 0):

> I fond the solution myself
>
> 100% working and fully tested

```
protected void grdName_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[8].Text.Length > 100)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[8].Text = e.Row.Cells[8].Text.Substring(0, 12);
                }


            }
        }
```